# Dynamic C/C++ lib for Android 2.2: error Symbol not found

Tags: android, dynamic, makefile, android-ndk

I have two projects. One of them is Android app with native code, which just loads dynamically library android_lib.so.

Another project is that library (android_lib.so). Code of this library is simple just for learning how things are going. It has only one function. Here is it:

```
int calculate (int x, int y)
{
  return (x*x+y*y);
}
```

In **Makefile** I use cross-platform compilator from Android 2.2 toolchains (/usr/local/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc):

```
NDK_DIR=/usr/local/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin
ANDROID_GCC=$(NDK_DIR)/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
NDK_ROOT=/usr/local/android-ndk-r8

CPPFLAGS = $(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include
CFLAGS =-nostdlib
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath-link=$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$(NDK_ROOT)/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/lib/
LIBS=-lc

android_lib.so: calculate.o
    $(ANDROID_GCC) $(CFLAGS)  -shared -o android_lib.so calculate.o 

calculate.o: calculate.c
    $(ANDROID_GCC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -fPIC calculate.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so
```

So I type make and get **android_lib.so**.
In native part of android project (it is mixed Java/C++ Eclipse project) I call dlopen()

```
dl_handle = dlopen( lib, RTLD_LAZY );
  if (!dl_handle) {
      error = (char *) dlerror();
      if (error != NULL) {
          __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"nativeCode",error);
          return -1;
      }
      else {
          sprintf(sError,"%s is not found",lib);
          __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"nativeCode",sError);
          return -2;
      }
  }
```

It succesfully loads android_lib.so. But if I am trying to call function calculate() I get error.

```
func = (int (*)(int, int)) dlsym( dl_handle, "calculate" );
  error = (char *) dlerror();
  if (error != NULL) {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"nativeCode",error);
      return -3;
  }
```

Function returns -3 and in LogCat of Eclipse I can see

```
01-01 07:00:44.624: I/nativeCode(8696): Symbol not found:
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

**Update**:

```
$ cd /usr/local/android-ndk-r8/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin 
$ sudo ./arm-linux-androideabi-objdump -T /home/chet/workspace/dinLib/android_lib.so

/home/chet/workspace/dinLib/android_lib.so:     file format elf32-littlearm

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000234 l    d  .text  00000000 .text
00000274 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 __exidx_end
000012e0 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 _bss_end__
00000234 g    DF .text  00000040 calculate
000012e0 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 __bss_start__
00000274 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 __exidx_start
000012e0 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 __bss_end__
000012e0 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 __bss_start
000012e0 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 __end__
000012e0 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 _edata
000012e0 g    D  *ABS*  00000000 _end
000012e0 g    D  .got   00000000 __data_start
```

Comment: Can you show output of "arm-linux-androideabi-objdump.exe -T android_lib.so" (to see if library have the "calculate" symbol)? Also - have you tried using ndk-build instead of inoking gcc manually to build shared library? Does that work?

Comment: @Mārtiņš Možeiko I have updated my post with output of this tool. I will try ndk-build. Thanks!

Comment: @Mārtiņš Možeiko I have compiled library using ndk-build. I get that error again(

Comment: Where are you putting this android_lib.so file on the device? Are you calling System.loadLibrary("android_lib.so") from Java?

Comment: android_lib.so is situated in /data/data/<app name>/lib 
I am loading it with dlopen(). After that, I am calling function with dlsym(). There is code in my question's post above.

Comment: It's strange that dlopen doesn't return error if you don't call System.loadLibrary on it... Maybe try changing RTLD_LAZY to RTLD_NOW?

Comment: And if I am using System.loadLibrary("android_lib.so"); I get Link error but dlopen("android_lib.so") works..

Comment: @Mārtiņš Možeiko , with RTLD_NOW again Symbol not found

Comment: I recreated my project. Now I am using System.LoadLibrary(android_lib.so) After this I am calling dlopen(android_lib.so). After dlsym returns symbol not found. 
I am not sure if I should call System.LoadLibrary because dlopen is alternative for this. @Mārtiņš Možeiko ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some important rules:

1. you should use `ndk-build` instead directly `arm-linux-androideabi-gcc`
2. in `Android.mk` of library type next options: `LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--export-dynamic`
3. if `dlerror()` returns error it doesn't mean that `dlsym()` failed. Check if `dlsym()` really returns `NULL`. Because it may return a valid address but `dlerror()` may return error "Symbol not found" at the same time %)) I had this stupid mistake!!! See code.
4. You do not need call `System.LoadLibrary(your_lib.so)`. Only `dlopen("your_lib.so")` from native code with `RTLD_NOW` or `RTLD_LAZY` no matter!
5. Be sure that `your_lib.so` is situated in `/data/data/app_name/libs`

   ```
   func = (int (*)(int, int)) dlsym( dl_handle, "calculate" );
   error = (char *) dlerror();
   if (error != NULL) { //replace it with if ((func == NULL)&& (error != NULL))
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,"nativeCode",error);
     return -3; 
   }
   ```

That's all :)